# Can I modify the email template to sendSignInLinkToEmail?

Tags: authentication

I can't find this template.
I already found the other templates for password recovery and email verification.
Thank you!

Read all documentation and couldn't find it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.